# Seeking an better way to add columns in data.table from lookup table

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to create a new column `key` in my data.table by merging with a lookup table by common columns `index1` & `index2`. Then from the values of this new `key` column (`a`,`b`,`c`), I'd like to generate 3 new columns (`a`,`b`,`c`) that indices the `value` column in the data.table.

My data.table looks like this:

```
    index1      index2    value
1       2          0     0.00
2       1          2    -5.00
3       3          2    -5.00
4       3          2    17.50
5       2          2    15.00
6       1          2    -7.50
7       3          2     3.75
8       1          2    -8.75
9       2          1    15.00
10      2          1    12.50
```

The lookup table is this:

```
 index1  index2  key
1    1        1   a
2    1        2   b
3    2        1   a
4    2        2   c
5    3        1   c
6    3        2   b
```

The end result is like this:

```
    index1     index2   value  key       a       b      c
1       2          0     0.00   NA      NA      NA     NA
2       1          2    -5.00    b      NA   -5.00     NA
3       3          2    -5.00    b      NA   -5.00     NA
4       3          2    17.50    b      NA   17.50     NA
5       2          2    15.00    c      NA      NA  15.00
6       1          2    -7.50    b      NA   -7.50     NA
7       3          2     3.75    b      NA    3.75     NA
8       1          2    -8.75    b      NA   -8.75     NA 
9       2          1    15.00    a   15.00      NA     NA
10      2          1    12.50    a   12.50      NA     NA
```

I tried solving it by first merging the data.table and the lookup table by `merge()`, then used `J()` three separate times to achieve the above result. I'm pretty new to data.table, but would love learn a more elegant way to solve this instead of repeating the procedure several times. Here's my code:

```
DT <- merge(DT, lookup, by=c('index1', 'index2'), all.x=TRUE)
DT <- data.table(DT)  #Don't know why but DT became a data.frame after merge()
DT[J("a"), a:=value]
DT[J("b"), b:=value]
DT[J("c"), c:=value]
```

Comment: I don't quite get the last part: `I'd like to generate 3 new columns (a,b,c) that indices the value in the data.table)`. What do you mean here? Could show your final output? Also how do you want to handle `NA` keys? merging it either way creates `NA`...

Comment: My apologies. Was trying to figure out how to label the code blocks. Now it's fully edited.

Comment: don't use `merge`. Use `lookup[DT]` instead (`X[Y]` syntax). You should set both tables key to `index1, index2` before doing that, of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you want to join on index1 & index2, you can use `merge` as you have or if you assign these as keys to each of your tables, then you can simply use `[]` to join.  (As in `DT[lookup]` )

```
 setkey(lookup, index1, index2)
 setkey(DT, index1, index2)
```

then you can iterate over each unique `key` from your `lookup` table as follows

```
 keyVals <- unique(lookup[, key])

 for (k in keyVals)
   DT[lookup[key==k], c(k) := value]
```

---

Results:

```
DT
#     index1 index2 value    a     b  c
#  1:      1      2 -5.00   NA -5.00 NA
#  2:      1      2 -7.50   NA -7.50 NA
#  3:      1      2 -8.75   NA -8.75 NA
#  4:      2      0  0.00   NA    NA NA
#  5:      2      1 15.00 15.0    NA NA
#  6:      2      1 12.50 12.5    NA NA
#  7:      2      2 15.00   NA    NA 15
#  8:      3      2 -5.00   NA -5.00 NA
#  9:      3      2 17.50   NA 17.50 NA
# 10:      3      2  3.75   NA  3.75 NA
```

Comment: `c(k)` is nice LHS syntax to avoid `with=FALSE`. Hadn't thought of that!

Comment: @MD Thanks. I got the idea from using `c(string1, string2)` for multiple assign in `LHS`

Comment: @MD, can you use `lookup[.(k)]` when not using the key of `lookup`?  If so, how would that work.  (please feel free to edit answer with appropriate syntax)

Comment: Think I've misunderstood that lookup bit then. Will take a deeper look later.

Comment: Worked out great! Thanks @RicardoSaporta! Had to upgrade my data.table() from ver 1.8.2 to fully harness the power!

Comment: @SeanM,  no sweat, glad to help