# Merge 2 R dataframes keeping matched rows from 2nd dataframe and unmatched from 1st

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I would like to merge 2 dataframes in by matching the id column in the following way

```
dfmain = 
  id  name val res
1  1    a    
2  2    b    
3  3    c    
4  4    d    
5  5    e
```

and

```
dfsub = 
  id name  val    res
1  2 two   true   thanks
2  4 four  false  Sorry
```

to get

```
dfmain =
   id  name  val    res
1:  1  a      
2:  2  two   true   thanks
3:  3  c      
4:  4  four  false  Sorry
5:  5  e
```

Please note that -

1. the columns in both the dataframes will remain the same in number and names
2. the id values in the second dataframe will always be a subset of those in the first dataframe

Currently I am using anti_join function to get unmatched rows in the first dataframe and joining the second dataframe to these rows

Is there any more efficient method to do this in place?

Tried using setDT from data.table library but I was only able to update values of one column at a time.

Sorry if I am missing any obvious solution that exists as I am new to R, any help would be appreciated

Comment: i think the idiomatic way is `cols <- c("name", "val", "res");
dfmain[dfsub, on=.(id), (cols) := mget(paste0("i.", cols))]`. This is most likely a dupe. for e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005666/seeking-an-better-way-to-add-columns-in-data-table-from-lookup-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you have in mind, otherwise please let me know. I noticed that you only replaced rows in dfmain with those of the same id in dfsub by also retaining the columns of dfsub, so here is how I think might get you to what you want:

```
library(dplyr)

dfmain <- tribble(
    ~id,  ~name, ~ val, ~ res,
  1,    "a",    NA,     NA,
  2,    "b",    NA,     NA,
  3,    "c",    NA,     NA,
  4,    "d",    NA,     NA,
  5,    "e" ,   NA,     NA
)

dfsub <- tribble(
    ~id, ~name,  ~val,    ~res,
  2, "two",   TRUE,   "thanks",
  4 ,"four",  FALSE,  "Sorry"
)

dfmain %>%
  filter(! id %in% dfsub$id) %>%
  bind_rows(dfsub) %>%
  arrange(id)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
     id name  val   res   
  <dbl> <chr> <lgl> <chr> 
1     1 a     NA    NA    
2     2 two   TRUE  thanks
3     3 c     NA    NA    
4     4 four  FALSE Sorry 
5     5 e     NA    NA
```

Comment: Yes, this is similar to what I want to do but just to clarify dataframe one will also have columns val and res but they will be empty (blanks or NA) initially (i.e. both dataframes will have same columns). I am doing the same process just using anti_join in dplyr ,just due to the sheer size of data (dataframe 1 being over 150000 rows with 20 columns and dataframe 2 being upto 2000 rows with 20 columns) I was looking for a more efficient method, will try this and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer by adding `val` and `res` columns to dfmain and got the same answer hope you do to.

Comment: Also if my data does not have a unique key, can I use multiple columns in the filter statement to match rows right - i.e filter ( ! (name1 %in% dfsub$name1 & name2 %in% dfsub$name2 &......))  provided that name1 and name2 column have same entries across both dataframes

Comment: If your data doesn't have unique id you can create it yourself by using `mutate(id = row_number)` for both data frames before using the code I suggested.

Comment: From the data you shared I realized a way to achieve your desired output is to replace rows of dfmain with rows of dfsub gathering the column of dfsub. If there are more scenario's involved we need you to share more information so that the proposed solutions are more efficient and stable.

Comment: I suggest you don't  use `filter ( ! (name1 %in% dfsub$name1 & name2 %in% dfsub$name2 &......)) ` for now just create `id`s if there aren't there and use the code to see what happens next.

Answer (score 0):

You can try (thank data by @Anoushiravan R)

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

setDT(dfsub)[setDT(dfmain),
  on = "id"
][,
  names(dfmain),
  with = FALSE
][
  ,
  Map(coalesce, .SD, dfmain)
]
```

which gives

```
   id name   val    res
1:  1    a    NA   <NA>
2:  2  two  TRUE thanks
3:  3    c    NA   <NA>
4:  4 four FALSE  Sorry
5:  5    e    NA   <NA>
```

Comment: I would also like rows from the first datafame which dont match ( something like a left join )